# Div rendering above (not on top of) another Div

Tags: jquery

I visit Stackoverflow all the time for answers (great resource), but this is my first question.

I have 2 divs I need rendered 1 above the other.
Should be very simple and I have done this many times.
My problem is that it renders opposite.
Instead of:
    div1
    div2
I am getting:
    div2
    div1

Been pulling my hair out for hours now.
Div1 is a jQuery jump menu
Div2 is a jQuery accordian list.
I display them via the show/hide method:

```
        $("a[id='faq_link']").click(function(){
        $("div[id='agent-buynow-form']").hide();
        $("div[id='mid-header']").hide();
        $("div[id='jump-menu']").hide();
        $("div[class='cat']").hide();
        $("div[id='cat-home']").hide();
        $("div[id='agent-page-header']").hide();
        $("div[id='agent-page-menu']").hide();
        $("div[id='agent-page-main']").hide();
        $("div[id='agent-page-commissions']").hide();
        $("div[id='agent-page-buycard']").hide();
        $("div[id='agent-page-buybulk']").hide();
        $("div[id='agent-page-newsletter']").hide();
        $("div[id='agent-page-offers']").hide();
        $("div[id='buynow-form']").hide();
        $("div[id='archive-list']").hide();

        $("div[id='jump-menu']").show();
        $("div[id='faq-list']").show();
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#faq-list')}, 'slow');          
//          alert("FAQ clicked");

        });
```

Jump Menu:

```
<!-- Begin Jump Menu -->
<div id="jump-menu" class="top">
<table align="left" border="1px" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
<tr>
    <td>
    Categories
</td>
<td>
    Current:
</td>
<td>
<div id="selection">
<select name="jumpMenu" id="jumpMenu">
    <option value="#cat-home" selected="selected">Home</option>
    <option value="#cat-dining">Dining</option>
    <option value="#cat-shows">Shows</option>
    <option value="#cat-tours">Tours</option>
    <option value="#cat-nightlife">Nightlife</option>
    <option value="#cat-shopping">Shopping</option>
    <option value="#cat-attractions">Attractions</option>
    <option value="#cat-golf">Golf</option>
    <option value="#cat-transportation">Transportation</option>
    <option value="#cat-spas">Spas</option>
    <option value="#cat-sports">Sports</option>
    <option value="#cat-events">Special Events</option>
    <option value="#cat-weddings">Weddings</option>

</select>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<!-- End Jump Menu -->
```

FAQ List:

```
<!-- Begin FAQ list -->
<div id="faq-list" style="display:none;">
<table>
<tr>
<td style="height:131px; line-height:15px; padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px;">
<div align="center"><B>--- FREQUENTLY ASKED QUESTIONS --- </B> </div>

<div id="accordion">
  <content>
    Does the ******* Card expire?
  </content>
  <div>
    Yes, all ******* Cards are valid one year from the date of purchase.
  </div>

  <content>
    How many places accept this card?  
  </content>
  <div>
    We currently have over 500 merchan
  </div>
  <content>
    How do I use my card?  
</content>
<div>
    Simply present your *********** at  
</div>
<content>
    What if I am traveling to ******** and do not have time for a card to be mailed to me?  
</content>
<div>
    When purchasing your card simp    
</div>
<content>
    Do the discounts change or will they always be the same?  
</content>
<div>
    We are continually adding new 
</div>
<content>
    Can I buy more than one card?  
</content>
<div>
    Yes, you can buy as many *****
</div>
<content>
    If the card is lost or stolen, can it be replaced?  
</content>
<div>
    Lost or stolen cards less than one year old can be replaced for the cost of shipping.   
</div>
<content>
    What do I do when my card expires?  
</content>
<div>
    Unfortunately, each ***** only   
</div>
<content>
    How long is each offer valid?  
</content>
<div>
    The merchants that provides
</div>
<content>
    Do I have to book things ahead of time?  
</content>
<div>
    You do not have to book in   
</div>
<content>
    Is there a customer service number people can call?  
</content>
<div>
    Yes, your card comes with our Customer service number.  
</div>
<content>
    Can locals use the card too?  
</content>
<div>
    Yes, locals are welcome to use the card as well.  
</div>
<content>
    Can I get a discount for my entire party?  
</content>
<div>
    For dinner reservations,    
</div>
</div>    
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<!-- End FAQ -->
```

I don't see anything unusual or out of the ordinary in the css either.

Other div's seem to show in the proper order.

Any ideas?

Thx

Comment: Is one of the elements floated? Either left or right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If things are showing up in the wrong order, location, etc., it is very likely a CSS issue, but as that is not included it's difficult to analyze.

Usually, if you want to show divs over top of other divs, you can do it with absolute positioning of divs inside of relative position divs.

You can find the specs for the "position" attribute here:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-position

Since the default is "position: static", you will likely need to override that to get the functionality you want.  If they are displayed out of order, it may be a result of "float" being used.

But again, without the CSS, this is very hard to determine.  jQuery will draw what you tell it to, but CSS controls where it draws it.

Comment: Thank's everyone for your input.  I have not been able to locate a css problem.  To get around the issue, I moved the location of DIV 1 (in the actual code) to be above DIV 2, DIV 3 etc and that worked.  It seems to me that the location of the div in code should not matter, but in this case it did.  My intention was to be able to shuffle each div around to different levels (up or down on the page) using just the hide/show.

Answer (score 0):

I know jQuery UI's accordion adds some floating styling to the elements, making it show above the other div. Either override these with !important or tinker with min-width for your first dive to get it to display correctly.

Comment: This happens with other div's also, not just the accordian.